# `gt` is not consistent with `gT` (and many other commands) when `{count}` is prepended

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, count

I know it's not a bug, since the `help` page explains it cleary, but is there any reason why `gt` is still kept different from the majority of commands that accept a `{count}` prepended? I mean, isn't it in contrast with `vi(m)` phylosophy?

What annoys me the most is that `gt` and `gT` are not the opposite of each other when a `{count}` is prepended (unlike many others, *e.g.* `n` and `N`, `w` and `W`, and so on), so, for instance, I can't "undo" a `2gT` by typing `2gt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really explain why it works like this, my best guess is that you more often need to go a tab by its index rather than going 3 tabs forwards.

However, if you really don't like how Vim works and want to be able to "undo" a `2gT` with `2gt` you can add the following to your vimrc:

```
function! Mygt(forward, count)
    let loop = a:count
    while loop > 0
        if a:forward
            normal! gt
        else
            normal! gT
        endif
        let loop = loop -1
    endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> gt :<C-U>execute "call Mygt(1, " . v:count1 . ")"<CR>
nnoremap <silent> gT :<C-U>execute "call Mygt(0, " . v:count1 . ")"<CR>
```

The function `Mygt()` is pretty straightforward: it takes 2 arguments, the first one is used to define if you want to go forward or backward in the list of tabs and the second one is how many tabs you want to skip. So it loops on the given count and repeats `gt` or `gT` according to the first parameter.

You can try it with `:call Mygt(1, 2)` or `:call Mygt(0, 4)`

To make it easier to use, we also remap `gt` and `gT`:

- `<silent>` is used to avoid prompting the function called by the mapping. (see [`:h :map-<silent>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap-%3csilent%3e))
- `<C-u>` is used to remove characters on the command line, it is used to allow a count to the mapping (see [`:h c_CTRL-U`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-U))
- We build the string which will contain the command to execute (e.g. `call Mygt(1, 3)` and execute it with `execute` (see [`:h execute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29))
- And finally, we use the count given to the mapping with `v:count1` which will default to `1` if no count is given. (see [`:h v:count`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3acount) and [`:h v:count1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3acount1))

All of this allows us to use `gt`, `gT`, `3gt` and `5gT` and get a "consistent" behavior.

Comment: Very nice solution! There's one thing I can't get: why have you written a function that overrides `gT` as well? It works like that already, it is `gt` the "misbehaving" one (at least imho).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis To be honest it is because when I developed it for my mappings (`<leader><leader>h` and `<leader><leader>l`) and I wanted two similar mappings instead of mapping `<leader><leader>l` to my function and `<leader><leader>h` to an invocation of `gt`. But I do agree that it is not necessary :)

Comment: Oh, I was on the point of honking you didn't notice or did misread that detail in the question. On the contrary you too overrode that behavior! I also sent an email about it to Bram Moolenaar some month ago, but he possibly ignored it :(

Comment: If you wrote to him directly he may have ignored it indeed. Usually people use the [vim-dev mailing list](https://www.vim.org/maillist.php) to discuss this kind of things :)

Comment: It has been discussed [previously](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/CTIIpzvcATY/klAn5voCCAAJ). It is probably an oversight. Now Bram does not feel like changing it to not break compatibility. So we would need a new command. It never bothered me to create a new command.

Comment: I don't think this extreme and no-matter-what care about backward compatibility will take us to the promised keyboard... Anyway, accepted answer, @statox!

Comment: that is your opinion. Other people might feel differently, if we change the semantics of a well-known command now. So he certainly has a point there.

Comment: I would certainly hate it.  I use a customized tab string that displays the tab number in the tab title and it's much easier to glance up and see the tab number than it is to look up and count how many tabs I want to jump forwards or backwards.  To my mind, this works very similar to {count}G jumping to a specific line number.  tabline is here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, sure it is my opinion and, as such, is debatable. I'm unhappy with that feature, but I agree that it's hard to compare what's more important (if any) between some users having to post questions and put a new function and mapping in their `.vimrc` and users/developers having to tweak the codes a bit (or a bit more than a bit). Speking of _well-known_-ess of these commands, I admit that I haven't checked any surveys to get slightest idea of how many vim users are power vim users and/or use tabs on non casual/non occasional basis. Anyway, your answer seems the solution!

Comment: @DanJ., I use lightline plugin, which shows tab numbers too, for some reason I find it easier to "count" tabs, possibly because I don't use more than 4, at most 5, of them. But this is certainly my misfortune. Btw, I wouldn't take `{count}G` into account, since I can't see any "sibling/nearly opposite" command for it; plus, commands to move `n` lines back and forth are as old as `vi`, namely `{count}k` and `{count}j`. I should definitely try to disable `gT` completely and rely on `gt` only, since the way it works it has no inverse command (like `G`).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80710/discussion-on-answer-by-statox-gt-is-not-consistent-with-gt-and-many-other).

Comment: @Enlico Ah! I was having trouble understanding the "change has been made in 8.2", but now I figured out what happened... Yeah, it's mostly the same. One change that was made is that `:tabnext` now takes a `+n` and `-n` argument, so when using the Ex command you can get an easier shortcut to repeat it twice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to write a function. You can take advantage of the fact that a macro prefixed by a count will be repeated as many times as the count says. And if you use the expression register for the macro you don't even waste a precious register or have a conflict with another use of the same register:

```
nnoremap gt @='gt'<cr>
```